# permanently store a value to be used in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary `self.total = defaultdict(int)` in my Order class that is used to input and print totals of every item that is ordered in my ordering system. Object are stored as

```
coffee_available=[Coffee(1, "1: Flat White", 3.50), 
            Coffee(2, "2: Long Black", 3.50), 
            Coffee(3, "3: Cappuccino", 4.00), 
            Coffee(4, "4: Espresso", 3.25), 
            Coffee(5, "5: Latte", 3.50)]
`
```

and the way I "order" these objects is by calling a function in my order class

```
    def order(self, order_amount, coffee_id):

        self.total[coffee_id] += order_amount
```

and i print each item type and their respective order amounts by using another function in my order class

```
def print_order(self):
    print(" ")
    print("Coffee Type\t\tAmount of Times ordered")                       
    print("-----------\t\t-----------------------")
    for coffee in coffee_available:

        print("{}\t- - -\t {} ".format(coffee.coffee_type,   self.total[coffee.coffee_id]))
```

this works well as each time my code is run in the same session it stores the `order_amount` value each time and displays it correctly, the only problem is that if i terminate the program it doesn't store the data for when i open it next. If I were to permanently store data how would I do it and what should i permanently store?

Comment: python `pickle` library is the key: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can make any `python` object to persist in a file using `pickle`. So lets say you want to persist the `total`

```
import pickle
# total is a dictionary
# to store it in a file
with open('total_dictionary.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(total, handle)

# lets say program terminated here
```

Now,

```
# to load it, if it was previously stored
import pickle
with open('total_dictionary.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
  total = pickle.load(handle)

# total dictionary is exactly same even if the program terminated.
```

So, your `order` method updates your `self.total` and `print_order` just views it. So basically you need to store the `self.total` after every update (`order` call). And, in the initializer of the class where you first declare `self.total`, you need to initialze `self.total` with dictionary loaded from pickled file (if it exists)

---

Just to be little more specific:

```
import pickle
..
def order(self, order_amount, coffee_id):
    self.total[coffee_id] += order_amount
    with open('total_dictionary.pickle', 'w') as handle:
        pickle.dump(total, handle)
```

and in `initializer` of the `Order` class

```
import os
..
def __init__(self):
    ...
    if os.path.exists("total_dictionary.pickle"):
        with open('total_dictionary.pickle', 'r') as handle:
            total = pickle.load(handle)
    else:
        total = defaultdict(int)
    ...
```

You can remove/delete `total_dictionary.pickle` to reset.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: so the way I use pickle is to store the values in the self.total dict and call it when I need  to call the order function later

Comment: the `order` function updates `self.total` and `print_order` accesses it. So all you need to do is: after each update call ie `order` call store the `total` dictionary in file using pickle. And in initializer of the class, make sure that if the pickled file is present then initialize total with that dictionary. Cool ?

Comment: thanks for the help, it works fine now. It doesn't store the very first order but thats fine

Comment: your update throws this error 'AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'exist'

Comment: updated. Mistake was that function is `os.path.exists` and not `os.path.exist`. plural 's'. Also make sure you have imported os module.

Comment: works perfect now, thank you

Comment: Am glad that it helped :)